# Design suggestion, failed to combine factory with generics

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm having trouble dealing with a design in Java for the following description:

I need to create a guitar shop that provides tuning service for different guitars.
Tuning is done differently for each guitar type.

I need to provide a design (classes and relations) that can deal with a basic scenario where a guitar needs to be tuned.

So I got:

- Guitar abstract\interface
- 2 Guitar implementations (Gibson and Fender)
- I got my GuitarShop
- GuitarService (interface\abstract)
- GibsonService (implements GuitarService)
- FenderService (implements GuitarService)
- GuitarService factory

[image]
So basically the factory gets the guitar type and returns the required guitar service. But the guitar service contains a method:

```
public void tuneGuitar(Guitar guitarToTune) {...}
```

Which means I need to cast my Guitar every time in each service (each guitar is tuned differently).

I tried using generics by templating GuitarService with 
But then my factory cannot serve me anymore (I cannot safely instantiate objects with parameters determined at run time).

Is there a best practice for such a scenario?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `my factory cannot serve me anymore (I cannot safely instantiate objects with parameters determined at run time).`

Comment: I think the problem he's facing is, that he's trying to apply polymorphic algorithms to concrete subtypes, but at runtime the only static information he has is the supertype of the guitars.

Comment: @Zymus try to implement the factory when using generics in the GuitarTunignService and see the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that your `Guitar` interface hides exactly the details that your factory needs to use to choose the appropriate `GuitarTuningService` implementation.  One way to approach the problem would be to implement the *Visitor* pattern, a.k.a. double dispatch.  The `Guitar` interface would get the following method:

```
public void accept(GuitarVisitor visitor);
```

Each `Guitar` implementation would, separately, implement the method the same way:

```
public void accept(GuitarVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

The `GuitarVisitor` interface would look like this:

```
public interface GuitarVisitor {
    public void visit(Fender guitar);
    public void visit(Gibson guitar);
    // other Guitar types as necessary
}
```

An implementation of `GuitarVisitor` performs the appropriate guitar-type specific behavior in each method.  For example, the `GuitarTuningServiceFactory` could use an inner `GuitarVisitor` implementation to select the appropriate `GuitarTuningService` for each provided guitar.  You cannot avoid a cast (though you can avoid type-safety warnings by performing it via `Class.cast()`), but you can safely perform it just once at the beginning of each `tune()` method, recording the downcast reference.

The main drawback of the `Visitor` pattern is that it locks in the possible types of the specific visited classes.  You can add a catch-all method to partially mitigate that (`public void visit(Guitar guitar)`).

Comment: Although this approach seems to look fine, it still can cause problems if the guitar hierarchy grows. You just can forget to add the overdriven method and things can go wrong without throwing any exception.

Comment: The problem is analogous to the expression problem. You either have to change all the operations, if you add a new type or change all types (cf. guitars), if you add a new operation.

Comment: Yes, it is a well-known shortcoming of the Visitor pattern that the visitor interface is tied to the hierarchy of visited classes.  I discussed it in the answer already.  A dependency on the hierarchy is inherent in this kind of problem, though, because the factory must be able to provide objects that are specific to `Guitar` implementations that are not known until runtime.

Comment: This is an acceptable answer, and the only one so far. I will give it a shot soon. If no better answer comes I will accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

Below I provided the solution you've asked for. But I'm not sure, if that is the solution you really need for your problem. Because I can't understand, why you need to model the properties of the different guitars by class type. But I can only assume.

### Approach 1 | Cast + recompilation per new service

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guitar f = new Fender();
        Guitar g = new Gibson();

        TuneService<Guitar> fts = TuneServices.getService(f);
        fts.tune(f);

        TuneService<Guitar> gts = TuneServices.getService(g);
        gts.tune(g);
    }

    static interface Guitar {
    }

    static class Fender implements Guitar {
    }

    static class Gibson implements Guitar {
    }

    // tune service that accepts only guitars as generic types
    static interface TuneService<T extends Guitar> {
        public void tune(T guitar);
    }

    static class FenderService implements TuneService<Fender> {
        @Override
        public void tune(Fender guitar) {
            System.out.println("Tune Fender.");
        }
    }

    static class GibsonService implements TuneService<Gibson> {
        @Override
        public void tune(Gibson guitar) {
            System.out.println("Tune Gibson.");
        }
    }

    // factory class
    static final class TuneServices {
        private static final Map<Class<?>, TuneService<?>> services;
        static {
            Map<Class<?>, TuneService<?>> tmp = new HashMap<Class<?>, TuneService<?>>();
            tmp.put(Fender.class, new FenderService());
            tmp.put(Gibson.class, new GibsonService());

            // populate services
            services = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
        }

        public static <T extends Guitar> TuneService<T> getService(T guitar) {
            TuneService<?> s = services.get(guitar.getClass());
            if (s == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            // cast is safe at this point
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            TuneService<T> ts = (TuneService<T>) s;
            return ts;
        }
    }
}
```

### Approach 2 | ServiceLoader + cast + no recompilation per new service

With this approach you don't have to recompile the factory as you add new guitar services,
you can even extend this approach in order to avoid recompiling, when you add a new guitar.

**ServiceLoaderExample.java**

```
package guitar;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class ServiceLoaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guitar f = new Fender();
        Guitar g = new Gibson();

        TuneService<Guitar> fts = TuneServices.getService(f);
        fts.tune(f);

        TuneService<Guitar> gts = TuneServices.getService(g);
        gts.tune(g);
    }

    static interface Guitar {
    }

    static class Fender implements Guitar {
    }

    static class Gibson implements Guitar {
    }

    // tune service that accepts only guitars as generic types
    static interface TuneService<T extends Guitar> {
        public void tune(T guitar);
    }

    // factory class
    static final class TuneServices {
        private static final Map<Class<?>, TuneServiceProvider<?>> providers;
        static {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ServiceLoader<TuneServiceProvider> loader = ServiceLoader.load(TuneServiceProvider.class);

            Map<Class<?>, TuneServiceProvider<?>> tmp = new HashMap<Class<?>, TuneServiceProvider<?>>();
            for (TuneServiceProvider<?> s : loader) {
                tmp.put(s.getGuitarType(), s);
            }

            // populate providers
            providers = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
        }

        public static <T extends Guitar> TuneService<T> getService(T guitar) {
            TuneServiceProvider<?> p = providers.get(guitar.getClass());
            if (p == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            TuneService<?> s = p.getService();

            // cast is safe at this point
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            TuneService<T> ts = (TuneService<T>) s;
            return ts;
        }
    }
}
```

**TuneServiceProvider.java**

```
package guitar;

import guitar.ServiceLoaderExample.Guitar;
import guitar.ServiceLoaderExample.TuneService;

public interface TuneServiceProvider<T extends Guitar> {
    public TuneService<T> getService();

    public Class<T> getGuitarType();
}
```

**FenderTuneServiceProvider.java**

```
package guitar;

import guitar.ServiceLoaderExample.Fender;
import guitar.ServiceLoaderExample.TuneService;
import guitar.TuneServiceProvider;

public class FenderTuneServiceProvider implements TuneServiceProvider<Fender> {

    @Override
    public TuneService<Fender> getService() {
        return new FenderService();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Fender> getGuitarType() {
        return Fender.class;
    }

    static class FenderService implements TuneService<Fender> {
        @Override
        public void tune(Fender guitar) {
            System.out.println("Tune Fender.");
        }
    }
}
```

**GibsonTuneServiceProvider.java**

```
package guitar;

import guitar.ServiceLoaderExample.Gibson;
import guitar.ServiceLoaderExample.TuneService;
import guitar.TuneServiceProvider;

public class GibsonTuneServiceProvider implements TuneServiceProvider<Gibson> {

    @Override
    public TuneService<Gibson> getService() {
        return new GibsonService();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Gibson> getGuitarType() {
        return Gibson.class;
    }

    static class GibsonService implements TuneService<Gibson> {
        @Override
        public void tune(Gibson guitar) {
            System.out.println("Tune Gibson.");
        }
    }
}
```

**/META-INF/services/guitar.TuneServiceProvider** must be on classpath or main/java/resources if you use maven

```
guitar.FenderTuneServiceProvider
guitar.GibsonTuneServiceProvider
```

### Output

The output is identical for both approaches.

```
Tune Fender. 
Tune Gibson.
```

### Drawback

Both approaches have the same drawback, **if** the service can be accessed by the client.

```
TuneService<Guitar> fts = TuneServices.getService(f);
fts.tune(f);

TuneService<Guitar> gts = TuneServices.getService(g);
gts.tune(g);

// use gibson service with fender
gts.tune(f);
```

A `ClassCastException` can be thrown at runtime, if the services are used with the super type `Guitar` and e.g. a FenderService is used with a Gibson and vice versa.
To avoid this, the service invocation could be encapsulated in a method, the get the right service (this method is already there) and applies it on the guitar.

Comment: I will have a closer look soon, but in first sight what seem wrong here is that you instanciate the guitars as concrete types while I like to instanciate those using the Guitar super type. Guitar g = new Gibson().

Comment: Indeed, if the declared type of the guitar object is `Guitar`, then type parameterization is no particular help.  You can nevertheless use a `Map` from `Class`es to `GuitarTuningService` implementations (or to objects than can provide such implementations), as this solution does, but doing so does not avoid the need to cast.

Comment: I can change it to use the supertype. But you either have to cast in the factory and provide a new service per guitar subtype or have the guitar interface accept a visitor and enhance the visitor for every new guitar subtype you provide. There are no other options in java.

Comment: Fixed it, only had to change the `main` method.

Comment: @mike Those are nice approaches and this is a useful answer but I prefer the visitor pattern, so accepting the other one although this is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
public interface GuitarTuningService<T extends Guitar> {

    void tune(T guitar);
}
```

And then

```
public class FenderTuningService implements GuitarTuningService<Fender> {

    public void tune(Fender guitar) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And in the factory

```
public class GuitarTuningServiceFactory {

    public GuitarTuningService getTuningService(final Guitar guitar) {
        if (guitar instanceof Fender) {
            return fenderTuningService;
        }
        // if guitar is a Gibson, return GibsonTuningService
    }

    private final GuitarTuningService<Fender> fenderTuningService
        = new FenderTuningService();
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but what's the point?  It has no type safety advantage because the factory method returns a bare type (which the compiler should warn about).  It *cannot* return a parameterized type that the user can use safely, because there is no such type compatible with both `Guitar` implementations.

Comment: Even making the `getTuningService()` method generic does not help if the `Guitar` implementation class passed to the factory is not statically known.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using generics by templating GuitarService with But then my factory cannot serve me anymore (I cannot safely instantiate objects with parameters determined at run time).

You can implement it like this:

```
// declare a common interface
public interface GuitarTuningService<GuitarGenericType extends Guitar> {
  void tune(GuitarGenericType guitar)
}

public class FenderTuningService implements GuitarTuningService<FenderGuitar> {
  public void tune(FenderGuitar guitar) {
    // tune it
  }
}
```

The factory in turn could be abstract:

```
public abstract GuitarServiceFactory<T extends GuitarTuningService> {
  T getGuitarService();
}

// and the concrete implementation:
public class FenderServiceFactory extends GuitarServiceFactory<FenderTuningService> {
  public FenderTuningService getGuitarService() {
    // instantiate & return FenderTuningService 
  }
}
```

And finally we can use this stuff like this:

```
public class GuitarTuner {

  private GuitarServiceFactory factory;
  private Guitar guitar;

  public GuitarTuner(Guitar guitar) {
    this.guitar = guitar;
    switch (guitar.getClass()) {
      case Fender.class:
        factory = new FenderServiceFactory();
        break;
      // other guitar types
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown guitar type added");
    }
  }

  public void tune() {
    factory.tune(guitar);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but it does not solve the stated problem (quoted in the answer).  How is the factory supposed to instantiate the correct service?

Comment: As I commented to Zymus, making `getGuitarService()` generic helps only if the specific `Guitar` implementation class can be determined statically at compile time.  That's a pretty heavy constraint.  Some problems cannot be solved by type parameterization.

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh, I see.. Somehow I misunderstood this and thought the TS was on the wrong way thinking of generics. One more edit to come.

Comment: Making the factor abstract and parameterizing its type *still* does not solve the problem.  It makes it worse, in fact.  Then, not only do you move the parameterization problem to the factory class (how does client code know which one it needs?), but then also the factory can serve only one guitar type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree, we are on the same page

Comment: well then there are two options: some sort of FactoryFactory which would return an actual factory implementation (which knows how to tune a `Guitar`) through `switch` or the one suggested by John (method overriding)